# Connecting to website's SOAP API with C#

Tags: c#, api, soap

I'm trying to connect to the a provider website which has a soap based API.  I'm new to C# so I am not really sure how to do it.  I've been googling around like mad but I am getting nothing but errors.  Here is what I've done.

I've added the URL (ex:http://www.companysite.com/api/api.cfc?wsdl) as a web service inside my .net solution and gave it a namespace of CompanyAPI.

If i right click on the service reference inside the solution explorer window, then go to object explorer.  I can see all of the available methods.

When i try to instantiate it is when I get errors like cannot instantiate an instance of abstract class.

```
'CompanyApi.Api MBApi = new MyApp.CompanyApi.Api();'
```

I have no clue what i am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a Service Reference in Visual Studio, it creates an interface to represent the service contract and a client class which implements the interface. You are probably attempting to create an instance of the interface directly, which is not allowed; you should create an instance of the client. The client should be named something like `ApiClient`, in which case you can do the following:

```
CompanyApi.ApiClient MBApi = new MyApp.CompanyApi.ApiClient();
```